# Angular custom tooltip sizing and positioning

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

In my Angular 15 project, I want to create a custom tooltip that can accept HTML text, can be styled with CSS, and can be oriented (top, bottom, right, or left).

However, my CSS skills are not very strong, so I'm having trouble positioning and sizing the tooltip correctly.

For example, when the element wrapped by the tooltip is positioned to the left and the tooltip orientation is set to 'top,' the tooltip extends beyond the window:
[image]

Here are the rules I want the tooltip to follow:

If the position is top or bottom:

- The tooltip should have a max-width equal to the window size minus a 30px margin.
- The edges of the tooltip should never go beyond the window and should respect the 30px margin.

If the position is right or left:

- The tooltip should have a max-width equal to the window size minus the position of the corresponding edge of the trigger element minus a 30px margin.
- The edges of the tooltip should be positioned relative to the trigger element, should never go beyond the window, and should respect the 30px margin.

Here is the code of my tooltip component:
Html:

```html
<div class="tooltip-wrapper">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <div
        #tooltip
        class="tooltip"
        [ngClass]="position"
        [ngStyle]="{'background-color': bgColor, 'color': textColor}"
    >
        <ng-container *ngIf="isTemplate; else textBlock">
            <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateRef"></ng-template>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template #textBlock>
            <div [innerHTML]="safeHtml"></div>
        </ng-template>
    </div>
</div>
```

Scss:

```
.tooltip-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

    .tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 9999;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 0.3s;
        width: max-content;

        &.top {
            bottom: 100%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -10px);
        }

        &.bottom {
            top: 100%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, 10px);
        }

        &.left {
            right: 100%;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-10px, -50%);
        }

        &.right {
            left: 100%;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(10px, -50%);
        }
    }

    &:hover {
        .tooltip {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Typescript:

```js
import {Component, Input, ElementRef, Renderer2, TemplateRef, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, HostListener} from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer, SafeHtml} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-tooltip',
    templateUrl: './tooltip.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./tooltip.component.scss']
})
export class TooltipComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    @Input() position: 'top' | 'bottom' | 'left' | 'right' = 'top';
    @Input() text: string | TemplateRef<any> = '';
    @Input() bgColor: string = '#333';
    @Input() textColor: string = '#fff';
    @ViewChild('tooltip', {static: false}) tooltipEl!: ElementRef;

    safeHtml: SafeHtml = '';
    isTemplate: boolean = false;
    templateRef: TemplateRef<any> | null = null;

    constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.isTemplate = this.text instanceof TemplateRef;
        if (this.isTemplate) {
            this.templateRef = this.text as TemplateRef<any>;
        } else if (typeof this.text === 'string') {
            this.safeHtml = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.text);
        }
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.adjustPosition();
    }

    @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
    onResize(event) {
        this.adjustPosition();
    }

    adjustPosition() {
        const triggerElementRect = this.elRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        const tooltipElement = this.tooltipEl.nativeElement;
        const tooltipElementRect = tooltipElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        const margin = 10;

        let maxTooltipWidth = 0;

        if (this.position === 'top' || this.position === 'bottom') {
            maxTooltipWidth = window.innerWidth - 4 * margin;
            this.renderer.setStyle(tooltipElement, 'maxWidth', `${maxTooltipWidth / 2}px`);

            let newLeft = triggerElementRect.left + triggerElementRect.width / 2 - tooltipElement.offsetWidth / 2;
            let newRight = triggerElementRect.left + triggerElementRect.width / 2 + tooltipElement.offsetWidth / 2;

            console.log(newLeft);

            if (newLeft < 0) {
                newLeft = margin;
                // console.log(newLeft);
                this.renderer.setStyle(tooltipElement, 'left', `${newLeft}px`);
            }
            // if (newRight > window.innerWidth) {
            //     newRight = window.innerWidth - margin;
            //     this.renderer.setStyle(tooltipElement, 'right', `${newRight}px`);
            // }

        }
        else if (this.position === 'left' || this.position === 'right') {
            maxTooltipWidth = this.position === 'left'
                ? triggerElementRect.left - margin
                : window.innerWidth - triggerElementRect.right - margin;

            this.renderer.setStyle(tooltipElement, 'maxWidth', `${maxTooltipWidth}px`);

            if (this.position === 'left') {
                let newRight = window.innerWidth - triggerElementRect.left + margin;
                this.renderer.setStyle(tooltipElement, 'right', `${newRight}px`);
                this.renderer.setStyle(tooltipElement, 'left', null);  // Réinitialiser le style 'left'
            } else {
                let newLeft = triggerElementRect.right + margin;
                this.renderer.setStyle(tooltipElement, 'left', `${newLeft}px`);
                this.renderer.setStyle(tooltipElement, 'right', null);  // Réinitialiser le style 'right'
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that the adjustPosition function doesn't set the tooltip correctly.

I am using my component in the following way:

```html
<app-tooltip
        [text]="'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus pretium dolor eget lacus elementum, quis scelerisque leo pellentesque. Sed condimentum consequat massa. Sed nibh nisi, sodales ut elementum non, bibendum ut ligula. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam laoreet molestie urna non sagittis. Vivamus placerat arcu ac ipsum imperdiet, eget vestibulum libero tempor. Sed pellentesque metus a libero cursus auctor in efficitur massa.'"
        position="top">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i>
    </app-tooltip>
```

Can someone help me with positioning and sizing the tooltip correctly or just let me know what's wrong with the code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey Trive! Thanks for the detailed question. Is it possible to show that output through a demo like Codesandbox so that people here can debug and let you know a good solution?

Comment: Here is a Codesanbox project with my tooltip component https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/charming-sanne-q4t2px.
Depending on the window size, the tooltip is displayed more or less correctly. Resizing the window does not properly recalculate the size and positioning of the tooltip.

Comment: I think you are on the right path, but I have a possible suggestion. I remember back in the day jQueryUI's tooltip plugin had some "generic" cardinal positions hard-coded as CSS classes like `n`, `s`, `e`, `w`, `ne,` `se`, `sw`, `nw` - meaning the tooltip would appear relative to the element in these positions. I believe a position could be hard-coded or it could figure out the best one for you.  Perhaps going this route might work well for what you need. EDIT: they use a different syntax than what I mentioned, but the idea is the same: https://api.jqueryui.com/position/